# JavaFx - No puedo crear el proyecto

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

Estoy intentando instalar JavaFx para aprender la herramienta. Sin embargo, estoy recibiendo ese mensaje de error. Cuando intento instalar el paquete que contiene JavaFx, no me muestra la opcion disponible para ser seleccionada. Alguien sabe que hacer aqui?

[image: Sin opcion para elegir otra plataforma]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo más probable es que el JDK que estás usando como "JavaFX Platform" no contenga a JavaFX.

Comment: Desde java se 9 javafx no esta por defecto en jdk

Comment: puede hacerlo a traves del plugin gluon que está en el listado de plugins del mismo netbeans